# Is it possible to Downgrade IIS Express 8 -> IIS Express 7.5 with VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, iis-express

We are looking to migrate VS2010->VS2012.

On installation VS2012 installs IISExpress 8 by default.  It does not appear that there is any way to disable this option.

Our production environment uses IIS7.5 so it would be desirable from a diagnostic point of view to maintain version parity between production and development environments.

Is there any way to downgrade from IISExpress 8 -> IISExpress 7.5 while still using Visual Studio 2012

Comment: Furthermore, I cannot find *any* information within Visual Studio 2012 about which version is installed.  Where can I find this info?

Comment: I think you can simpyly uninstall IIS Express 8 after installing VS then install IIS Express 7.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an asnwer to this in IIS forums:

Reference: [here](http://forums.iis.net/t/1194023.aspx/1?IIS+Express+7+5+with+VS+2012)

**Question:***

> Is it possible to install Visual Studio 2012 and exclude IIS Express 8.0 from the install package? It's not listed as a customizable option in the AdminDeployment.xml file.

**Answer:**

> Yes, you can. You can try to uninstall IIS Express 8.0 using add or
>   remove a Windows Component in  Control Panel. Please navigate to
>   "Programs and Features" in control panel, then uninstall     "IIS 8.0
>   Express".

---

**Question:**

> Is it possible to uninstall IIS Express 8 and re-install IIS Express
>   7.5 after the fact?

**Answer:**

> In my opinion, yu can re-install it. However, you need to make sure
>   that it has been installed in the following Windows editions which IIS
>   7.5 Express supports.
>
> Windows 7 Windows Server 2008 Windows Server 2008 R2 Windows Vista SP1
>   or later Windows XP SP3 Windows Server 2003 SP2 Both 32-bit and 64-bit
>   systems are supported, however only a 32-bit build of IIS 7.5 Express
>   exists.